# Android lost application data (/data/data/com.app.app/files)

Tags: java, android, file, android-file

I have problem with my app.

Saves the data in the following way:

```
private void saveUserData(String data2) {
    try 
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(data2.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        returnException(e.toString());
    }
}
```

and reads:

```
private void readUserData() throws IOException {    
    FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("config.txt");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line1 = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            line1 = reader.readLine();

            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                login = line1;
                login_editText.setText(line1);
                break;
            case 1:
                passmd5 = line1;
                break;
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    returnException("trwa logowanie..", false);

    if(checkUserData(login, passmd5))
    {
        returnException("zalogowano!", false);
        whoLogged_label.setText("tak ("+ login +")");
    }
    else 
    {
        returnException("błędne dane użytkownika!", false);
        whoLogged_label.setText("nie");
    }

    isr.close();
    fIn.close();
}
```

The phone is restarted once an hour and it happens that the file is automatically deleted. Why file disappears? I cannot diagnose the cause of.
After reboot file is empty.

Comment: First of all, what are you saving in this file? The file name "config" indicates another problem, saving app config information should be done in the SharedPreferences.
I know this dosen't help your question, but maybe this can help you.
Also, the file is saved on your SD card?

Comment: @GhostDerfel - there is absolutely no problem with saving information in a custom file rather than shared preferences (shared preferences itself is ultimately a file).  The use of the openFileOutput method indicates that the file is saved in the internal storage.

Comment: This "restarted once an hour" business is extremely unusual.  Perhaps this atypical android device also does a cleanup of application private storage on a regular automatic basis as well.  Try you app on a normal device or emulator and you will likely find it works fine.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I know that there is no problem in doing something like that, but using the SharedPreferences can resolve his problem, also I think creating a file do manage config information seems to me maybe he didn't now the posibility of SharedPreferences.
And your are more correct then me in your comment since you focused on his question.

Comment: I have no idea where it was a mistake.
I used Shared Preferences and for now works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're not getting an exception when writing the file, I don't see anything obvious in your code. openFileOutput() writes files in the app's private internal storage directory, which is cleared whenever the app is uninstalled. Are you sure you're no part of your reboot/rerun process is doing an app uninstall or data-clear?

Comment: I have no idea where it was a mistake.
I used Shared Preferences and for now works properly.